# Evaluate $\int\cdots\int_{\mathbb R^n}\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i^me^{-x_i^2}}{e^{\frac{x_i}2}\cosh(\frac{x_i}2)}\mathbb dx_1 \cdots \mathbb dx_n$

Tags: integration, special-functions, spherical-coordinates

I'm wondering how can we evaluate
$$\int\cdots\int_{\mathbb R^n}\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i^me^{-x_i^2}}{e^{\frac{x_i}2}\cosh(\frac{x_i}2)}\mathbb dx_1 \cdots \mathbb dx_n$$
using Gamma/Beta functions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am new to the community and I post some old exams problems I found while studying for mathematical methods of physics. The truth is I have made almost 0 progress on the ones I post

Comment: I will try not to post such questions and to contribute to the community with effort!

Comment: Thanks for the edit!!

Comment: I also wanted to ask you, if a problem I posted received 0 answers, shall I post it again?

Comment: When $m$ is even, the integral reduces to $$\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^me^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^n=\Gamma\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)^m.$$ When $m$ is odd, even the simplest case $n=1$ and $m=1$ yields $$-2\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x^2}\tanh(x/2)\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\operatorname{sech}^2(x/2)\,\mathrm{d}x,$$ which I am not sure how to tackle.

Comment: Can you tell me how you get this integral ? It seems right thought

Comment: When $m$ is even, then note that \begin{align*}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^me^{-x^2}}{e^{x/2}\cosh(x/2)}\,\mathrm{d}x&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^me^{-x^2}}{e^{x/2}\cosh(x/2)}+\frac{(-x)^me^{-(-x)^2}}{e^{-x/2}\cosh(-x/2)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}x^me^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x.\end{align*} The last integral reduces to the gamma function via the substitution $t=x^2$.

Comment: Thanks, I will post if i find the answer for m=odd

Comment: I couldnt find anything for m=odd..